# What is the difference betwen @Input and @Output in Angular2

Tags: angular

I am just learning Angular2 and I came across @Input and @Output. What is the difference between the two.

Answer (score 29):

`@Input()` is to pass data **In** to the component

```
class ChildComponent {
  @Input() data;
}

@Component({
  template: `<child [data]="parentData"></child>
})
class ParentComponent {
  parentData;
}
```

Here `ParentComponent` is passing data to the child by the `@Input()` property. The `[data]` is the same name as the *property* in the child component. If you want to use a different name than the property name, then you can use `@Input('diff-name')`

`@Output` is to emit data (events) **Out** from a component

```
class ChildComponent {
  @Output() dataChange = new EventEmitter();

  click() {
    dataChange.emit('new Value');
  }
}

@Component({
  template: `<child (dataChange)="onDataChange($event)"></child>
})
class ParentComponent {

  onDataChange(event) {
    console.log(event);
  }
}
```

Here `ChildComponent` has an `@Output` that it emits events to. The parent is listening and passes a callback to the `(dataChange)`. Now every time the child emits an event, the parent callback will be called passing the event.

Comment: Thank you @peeskillet, when do we need to use EventEmitter. What type of needs does it solves?

Comment: It could be any number of use cases where you want to emit some value to the parent. You probably need to just start building a project. You will most likely run into this situation, then you hit that "AHAH moment" and realize the EventEmitter would be perfect :-). Just know that anytime you see `(something)="callback()"`, there is an EventEmiiter behind the scenes. That might give you some insight

Comment: EventEmitter e @OutPut sempre andam juntos? +1

Answer (score 1):

For AngularJS, we can exchange data by $scope, parent scope and root scope, but not Angular. I think @Input is very easy, so let me focus @Output.

Usually, we can use Service sync data between any components.

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject, Subscription } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class OneService {
  public oneSubject: Subject<Object> = new Subject<Object>();
}
//And we can use it in component
export class ComponentA {
  public dataFromService = null;
  constructor(private oneService: OneService) {
    this.oneService.subscribe(data => this.dataFromService = data);
  }
}
//We also can emit changes from other object
export class ComponetB {
  public oneData = false;
  constructor(private oneService: OneService) {
  }
  onChange() {
    this.oneService.next(this.oneData);
  }
}
```

So, @Output to simplify above logic between parent/children components.

Warning: It is not mean @Output equal subject/subscribe, only make helpful about how to understand output.

Answer (score 0):

`@Input` and `@Output` Decorators are parts of the @angular/core.

`@Input` decorator binds a property within one component (child component) to receive a value from another component (parent component). This is one way communication from parent to child.

`@Output` decorator binds a property of a component to send data from one component (child component) to calling component (parent component). This is one way communication from child to parent component.

for the reference 
[angular.io/guide/component-interaction]

Comment: Can you please update your answer and add some relevant detail so that it complements or expands other answers. Currently your answer only adds the angular library name, but that's doesn't really address the question "What is the difference between `@Input` and `@Output` in Angular2"

Comment: `@Input` decorator binds a property within one component (child component) to receive a value from another component (parent component). This is one way communication from parent to child. 

`@Output` decorator binds a property of a component to send data from one component (child component) to calling component (parent component). This is one way communication from child to parent component.

This link will help you for the more reference [https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction]